# How to determine statistical significance of one independent variable by two dependent variables?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chemometrics

(I originally asked a syntax question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602846/bracket-syntax-issue-in-a-loop), but in addition to an answer I was told my statistics method itself wasn't great - so now I'm here!)

Without getting too into it, we did different chemical treatments to a sample and took spectroscopy data after each time (treatment = line in the data below). I want to know statistically which wavelength this had an effect on. The values under each line number are their absorbance data.

My goal is to be able to look across each wavelength (row) and determine if the changes in absorbance can be accounted for by the treatments. r^2 sounded the best for the job, but now I'm not so sure. To be clear, the wavelengths are being treated independent of each other at this point (but eventually I would like to plot whatever statistic variable I use by wavelength to see trends).

The first 5 wavelengths of the dataframe look like this:

```
  Wavelength    Line_1    Line_2    Line_3    Line_4    Line_5    Line_6    Line_7
1       0400 0.4054731 0.3193632 0.2667026 0.8494675 0.2394639 0.2936054 0.2453124
2       0402 0.4048527 0.3195507 0.2693250 0.8664931 0.2380499 0.2931895 0.2437657
3       0404 0.4041760 0.3226145 0.2731347 0.8756971 0.2338797 0.2876017 0.2432391
4       0406 0.4079322 0.3264623 0.2750645 0.8770746 0.2273580 0.2866682 0.2476563
5       0408 0.4158769 0.3271127 0.2790707 0.8770176 0.2268334 0.2947697 0.2567014
```

How would any of you approach this problem?

**6/30 edit** Here's a transposed version of the data (excluding ~3500 more columns):

```
 dataPoint    0400        0402        0404        0406         408
1   Line_1  0.4054731   0.4048527   0.404176    0.4079322   0.4158769
2   Line_2  0.3193632   0.3195507   0.3226145   0.3264623   0.3271127
3   Line_3  0.2667026   0.269325    0.2731347   0.2750645   0.2790707
4   Line_4  0.8494675   0.8664931   0.8756971   0.8770746   0.8770176
5   Line_5  0.2394639   0.2380499   0.2338797   0.227358    0.2268334
6   Line_6  0.2936054   0.2931895   0.2876017   0.2866682   0.2947697
7   Line_7  0.2453124   0.2437657   0.2432391   0.2476563   0.2567014
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your data. Where are the treatments? Are the `Line`s 7 different treatments, or 1 treatment tried 7 different times? Something else?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica the treatments are the column headers, eg 'Line_1' is the first treatment, 'Line_2' is the second treatment, etc.. The big picture hypothesis is that with each successive treatment wavelengths will change.

Comment: So is it 1 treatment 7 times, & each additional time is like increasing the dose?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica more or less, yes. Each time is a successive chemical treatment being repeated on the sample

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica do you think r^2 is a good route to go? Or would something like SSm, etc. be more appropriate?

Comment: It's hard for me to say.  I put the `[chemometrics]` tag on your Q.  Hopefully someone with more expertise in this area will come along.  I still don't quite understand your setup.  I would have expected the data to be more similar within each wavelength than between, & the absorbance would either progressively increase or decrease w/ each additional application of the treatment.  However, the data clearly seem more similar within each treatment than within each wavelength, & from i treatments to i+1 treatments, the absorbance bounces around randomly.  So I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica That pattern is baseline shifting - something else I'll have to work around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. it would be more usual to present the transpose of your data: each sample (chemical terminology) or case (stats terminology) as a row, the different wavelengths/measurement channels / variates as columns.

Comment: 2. Without knowing what kind of spectroscopy you did, what the units of the intensity axis are, and what treatments you did it will be extremely difficult to advise. We'd probably also need to know what application question you want to answer.

Comment: 3. For most types of spectroscopy, a well measured data set has many data points per band/peak. Neighbouring wavelengths are therefore correlated. Are you interested in significance per measurement channel or per band? 4.  Many spectra consist of many bands. Testing them all for significance gets you into a severe multiple testing situation. If you actually want to check statistical significance of single bands, you are probably much better off if you start by putting up a few hypotheses which bands may be significant, then integrating the respective intensities and perform a significance test

Comment: ... on those aggregated data.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX 1.) I'll update my question with that once I've done it. 2.) It's FTIR, the absorbance units are cm-1. The question we're asking is just 'which peaks did each successive treatment had an effect on.' 3.) I'm not sure I can differentiate them - the data is a raw .csv from our machine. 4.) That makes sense, but the data is messy and right now we're pretty much exploratory. I can try to bin out the peaks later, but eventually I'll run into the same question of what kind of statistical test to use.

Comment: @Mulligan: if you plot the whole spectra, we'll see 3 But for FTIR on condensed matter, bands are typically far more broad than 2 cm⁻¹. 4. of course. But we cannot even tell you sensible approaches to construct a test without knowing details about your treatments and the big question behind the data. Iff you can formulate the hypothesis you want to test as something like "is there a significant shift of the >C=O stretching band position?" or "is there a significant change in the intensity of the >C=O stretching band under treatment?" we could advise on a test in a pretty straightforward ...

Comment: fashion (after knowing more details on the treatment). But "is there anywhere any significant change with the treatment" is a much less well posed question, and chemometrically sensible approaches to tackle it in a way that gives you useful information is easily outside the area where we can construct hypothesis tests. To put it in a different way, constructing a meaningful hypothesis test here would be work well worth its own paper, and possibly a whole PhD thesis.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to ask: how many replicates do you have for each treatment level, and are the treatment levels supposed to have a linear effect (in the chemical sense of the word) or one that you'd know how to transform so that one could assume linearity?

Comment: 1/2 @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I agree I could see the bands if they were graphed, I'm talking about getting those bands cleaned up in the csv. The reason I haven't given much info is because I was kinda just given the data for many different treatments on many samples (the data above is one sample/treatment) and I'm trying to make a r pipeline to spit out stats - and interpret them sample by sample. The treatments are successive chemical washes of a sample, and each FTIR reading should hypothetically show lower absorbances of everything - but we're finding it's only working on sporadic peaks.

Comment: 2/2 @cbeleitesunhappywithSX As far as I know, there were not replicates (same same same treatment). I would assume a linear effect, but again we found it has sporadic results.

Comment: Do you have particular reasons for assuming repeated washing to have a linear effect? I'd have expected exponential, i.e. each washing cycle to take aways a ≈constant fraction of the substancce in question. Replicates: it is all the same sample washed several times? No 2nd sample was washed?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX We're testing methods for eluding material off a sample to be read on FTIR - each wash removes material and we would assume everything disappears eventually. I suppose exponential decay might be more realistic. Yes, each sample was washed several times, and we have ~300 samples

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Do you know of any way, statistical or not, that I could at least narrow down which peaks are changing - apart from baseline shifts? On a graph they mostly line up when you normalize them all to their max heights instead of a common scale. If I could get to that point I could do a more appropriate stats test. I'd prefer not to do it visually for consistency and time efficiency. Of course, all of this is starting to sound futile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough ideas:

If you think that you can sensibly expect a linear correlation between (absorbance) spectra and washing cycle or log washing cycle (zero washing would then function as baseline), you could try PLS regression.
With PLS you can fairly easily bootstrap the samples and thus generate distributions for the coefficient patterns over the wavenumber and check whether the distribution is sufficiently away from zero.
You may also look into Alessandro Olivieri's work whether he has analytical expressions to calculate significance - but AFAIK, that would not account for the sample x washing structure.

If PLS is too restrictive, MCR-ALS may be another possibility: there, you'd not require exactly linear relationship to washing (or log washing), but you can put a constraint that only decreasing intensities qualify.

IMHO significance is very difficult here, because of the physical correlations in the spectra. You can take care of neighbouring wavelengths being correlated by lookign at band integrals, but that will still leave you with correlation between, say, symmetric and anti-symmetric and the respective deformation vibrations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll definitely look into PLS. I think at this point I'm just going to plot out the sum difference in the absorbances in a violin plot, overlaying broad molecular classes in the background as a key. Hopefully that'll be sufficient while I work out the best way to do this mathematically.